# telegraf snmp date field

Tags: snmp, telegraf

I want to monitor vpn connections. For this I need an snmp query, with telegraf, but I can't get the data.
My telegraf config:

```
[[inputs.snmp]]
  agents = [ "172.30.124.2" ]
  version = 2
  community = "telegraf"

  [[inputs.snmp.field]]
    name = "vpnclients"
    oid = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.392.1.3.35"
```

When I run a test, I got:

```
telegraf --config telegraf.d/cisco0.conf --test --debug 
2019-10-22T08:12:13Z I! Starting Telegraf 1.12.3
2019-10-22T08:12:13Z D! [agent] Initializing plugins
2019-10-22T08:12:13Z D! [inputs.snmp] Executing "snmptranslate" "-Td" "-Ob" "-m" "all" ".1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.392.1.3.35"
```

with snmpwalk:

```
snmpwalk -c telegraf -v 2c 172.30.124.2 "1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.392.1.3.35"
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.392.1.3.35.0 = Gauge32: 7
```

I don't know why telegraf don't made a query. I try with other OID's, and only with this one I had problem.

Answer (score 1):

I try to find another OID to query the active connections, and I found it:
1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.392.1.3.1.0

this OID is works with telegraf